# Unable to create indicator variables

Tags: stata

I am using the following code to create indicator variables

```
tab district, gen(dist_id)
```

However, I am getting error r(134) which says "too many values".

The number of distinct values in district are about 15000, and I have used the `set maxvar 25000` command to accommodate the new variables. I am running Stata SE 12.1.

Could someone point out the mistake in the above command or an alternate method to construct the variables?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Right now, this looks like a pure Stata question, which is off topic here. But you may have a statistics question as well - why do you have 15000 distinct variables and need indicator variables for them?

Comment: I am trying to include fixed effects at district level in my regression, and have 15000 districts, hence the indicator variables.

Comment: OK, but I hope you have a LOT of data.

Comment: Yes, I have more than 500,000 observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a loop with `levelsof` command works for this.

```
levelsof district, local(xxx)
foreach lev of local xxx {
    gen x_`lev'=0
    replace x_`lev'=1 if district==`lev'
    }
```

This solution is mentioned By Dan Palmer on the Statalist.org page linked here https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1490495-use-a-for-loop-to-generate-dummy-variables

Comment: The thread you cite mentions a much better solution!

Comment: Do you mean tab, gen? My post mentions that this is not working for me.

Comment: You are correct. A fuller discussion would need to explore why you (think you) need so many extra variables. Factor variable notation usually makes them unnecessary.

Comment: I tried with factor variable notation too, but still got an error. I am using the variables to control for fixed effects, and my data is cross sectional.

Comment: I’d take your problem to Statalist.